# Always start Yosemite calendar on today

Tags: macos, calendar

In my previous version of OSX (Snow Leopard), Calendar always opened to the month, week, or day that includes (or is) today.  In Yosemite, Calendar opens to whatever month/week/day you had open when you closed Calendar.

I can easily understand why Yosemite Calendar's "last open" behavior might be very desirable for some people, but for me it's very dangerous.  I know that I can jump to today using the button in the upper right corner--if I remember--and there's the problem.  I'm so used to Snow Leopard Calendar's behavior, that when I open Calendar, I just assume that I'm looking at the current month/week/day.  I don't know when I will miss an appointment because of this "feature", but I know it will happen.

Is there a way to cause Yosemite Calendar to always open to the current month/week/day?  I've been unable to find anything in Calendar's Preferences that will accomplish this.

Comment: I opened Calendar, chose the Day view, went back to 10 Aug then quit the application. When I opened it it was back on 25 Aug? Doesn't yours do the same? :)

Comment: No!  Weird.  I thought that maybe the difference was that I was closing at a date in the future, while you're closing at a date in the past, but I have the same problem with past dates.  I have Yosemite 10.10.5.  Perhaps it's relevant that I didn't do a clean install?  I did the upgrade install with from my Snow Leopard setup.

Comment: Weird. Have you cleared PRAM and SMC? I got El Capitan tho, maybe they fixed it. Can someone else test on Yosemite?